# Setting a child execution variable sets parent execution with value null

Tags: jbpm

If I set an execution variable in child it gets in parent as well. [That agrees with variable scoping doc here](http://docs.jboss.com/jbpm/v4/userguide/html_single/#d0e5153).

But for child execution the value is actual value I set and for parent the value of the variable is null.

I am at a loss to explain this behaviour. Why only set the key but not value in parent execution?

In child execution

```
child.setVariable("somekey", "somevalue");
```

In child execution

```
child.getVariable("somekey");
```

returns "somevalue"

In parent

```
parent.getVariable("somekey");
```

returns null.

I would have expected the value to be the same going by variable scoping doc.

Version 4.4

Comment: could you show me your process definition file?

Comment: @swemon we do a dynamic fork and join not through jpdl as we don't know number of children before hand.